# How can we use layouts in Android like divs of HTML?

Tags: android

I want to use Layouts, like we use divs in HTML, i.e. 2 Divs in a screen to separate navigation bar with content. Can we do this by using layouts, if yes then how can we do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible using android styles in android. You can define style for similar widget properties like colour, padding, background, text size etc. Once you have styles, you can apply those styles while defining a widget (TextView, EditText etc..) in xml layout files. More details about styles are available at following link.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html